# Permission Issues When Pushing to Git Remote

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, file-permissions

I've spent the past few days trying to set up a Git Remote on my server so I can push changes to my web-server to it. The problem is that I'm getting the following errors while doing it:

```
$ git push --porcelain --progress --recurse-submodules=check live refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
'master' pushed: d689cce..4e755fc
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitignore (Permission denied)        
remote: error: unable to create file .gitignore~ (Permission denied)        
remote: error: unable to create file index.js (Permission denied)        
remote: error: unable to create file package.json (Permission denied)
```

Now, I get that this has something to do with file and folder ownership, and that I and/or git may or may not have write access to certain folders.

Trouble is I don't have the faintest clue which folder I can't write to or how to resolve it.

I'm brand new to messing with setting up a web-server from scratch, so here's what I did:

I went through [How To Set Up Automatic Deployment with Git with a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) to try and see how I should get the remote up and running. This lead me to create the following two folders: `/var/repo/site.git` and `/var/www/website`.

Without being told anything about permissions I went ahead and tried to push to the remote as told, immediately running into the first permission roadblock.

So I consulted a friend who suggested I should make a new group, add my user to the group, and then have `/var/repo` be owned by said group with the `775` read/write/execute permissions. He also suggested I should do as suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=919951&p=5791162#post5791162) to make sure the `/var/www` folder had the right permissions; but even after all that I still can't push to the remote as shown in the error above.

So what am I supposed to do to fix this? I'm kinda at a roadblock here.

Some info about the stuff I use:

- Client OS: OSX Yosemite
- Server OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- Git Client: SmartGit 6.5 (for convenience)
- I use SSH rather than HTTPS to connect to the remote

Comment: Does each user have their own system user account, where they push to ssh://username@gitserver? Or is there just a single git@gitserver account with keys for different users?

Comment: @Will there's root@server, user@server, but I don't know if there's a git@server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not write access on /var/repo - I believe from the errors you've copied/pasted that this is set up correctly and probably always was.

The issue is a lack of write permissions on /var/www.

By following the instructions you've linked to what you've set up is a script that automatically takes the files you push to the git repository on the server and publishes them in /var/www. This is a smart approach in my opinion, but that script (which lives in the file /var/repo/hooks/post-receive) is being run as the same that pushes to the git repository. That user doesn't appear to have permission to write to /var/www

Assuming you've already followed the steps from the previous answer, these two additional commands should put things right:

```
chown -R root:git-users /var/www/

chmod -R g+rw /var/www/
```

Comment: I figured I could just have the user be a member of two different groups and still have it work.. but I guess not. This worked

Comment: Good catch! I was thinking this was on the git-repo side :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said in the comments that users push to git via their `username@server`, you need to make sure all git users have read and write permissions to the repository.

Add all users to a common group, called, say, `git-users`.

```
groupadd git-users
```

Now add each git user to the group:

```
usermod -a -G git-users <username>
```

Now, change the ownership group for the git repository:

```
chown -R root:git-users /var/repo/
```

Now, set permissions such that the group can read and write to the repo:

```
chmod -R g+rw /var/repo/
```

Now, any member of the group `git-users` has read and write access.

Now we need the `setgid` bit for directories only:

```
 find /var/repo/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Additionally, you need to enable the `sharedRepository` setting in the remote git configuration:

```
[core]
sharedRepository = true
```

Comment: Didn't change a thing. What you said is essentially the same as what my friend told me, and even doing everything you said step by step I still get the same errors

Comment: Try what I just added in my edit. It does seem that there's more to it. If this still doesn't work, report back :)

Comment: Same error, I added that line to the `config` file I found in `site.git`.. not working

Comment: Did you do the `g+s` part? So if that's still not working, try `sharedRepository = group` rather than `sharedRepository = true`.

Comment: do I need to re-init the git folder or something, cuz it's still not working

Comment: look at the other answer, it solved the issue